# Initialize application scoped variables

Tags: servlets, soap, wsdl

I have a JSP-based Webapp which is accessing a SOAP-Service for some auth-credentials verification.
I want to put this Services URL in a application-scope Variable so I can easily pass to the SOAP-calls. Whats the best way to do this? Put it in a init-param and then on pass it to application.wsdlurl on init?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You mentioned JSP in title and tags, but you're talking about a servlet. While JSP ultimately get compiled as a servlet, a JSP is not the same as a servlet.

Comment: Sorry for the crappy question. I have a JSP-based Authentication-Site. Auth-Backend ist accessed through SOAP (JAX-WS). There will be multiple instances of this application. So the Auth-URL needs so be configurable per environment. I read about getInitParameter() and application scope for applicationwide access to the URL. But where would i define that?

Thanks again!

Comment: You can indeed just use init-param for this. I posted an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define it as `<init-param>` in servlet's definition in `web.xml`.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.YourServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>wsdlurl</param-name>
        <param-value>http://...</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

You can assign it as an instance variable of the servlet as follows:

```
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private String wsdlurl;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        wsdlurl = getServletContext().getInitParameter("wsdlurl");
        // Do if necessary some validation.
        // E.g., if null, then throw ServletException.
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This may sound newbie-ish but i just built my application with all the necessary frontend-logic straight in the webapps / (root). The more complex auth-soap part is wrapped in classes (WEB-INF/classes/$packages). I know this is not really considered "best practise" but it does the job with no real drawbacks (afaik). How would I make these params accessible to frontend (/.. ) and backend (classes)?

Comment: If they have access to the `ServletContext`, you could set it as an attribute of it. But if they haven't then you should forget the init-param approach and use a properties file instead and create a class which loads and holds it statically.

Comment: to my knowledge you grant access with the "<servlet-class>com.example.YourServlet</servlet-class>" directive how would this look like for my  /*.jsp setup?

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand your question. Grant access? What do you mean? Do you need this value in JSPs as well? Just set it as an attribute of `ServletContext`. E.g. `getServletContext().setAttribute("wsdlurl", wsdlurl);`. It'll be available in JSPs by `${wsdlurl}`.

Comment: I tried this <param> stuff before and it always returned NULL. I was assuming that you'd explicitly define these params for a certain class. I'll try with your approach. Thanks!